# Application fails creating a windows station with CreateWindowStation

Tags: c++, windows

I can't create a new Window Station to run my application

```
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    wprintf(L"SetProcessWindowStation() before: %x\n", GetProcessWindowStation());
    HWINSTA winSta = CreateWindowStation(_T("hiddenWinSta"), 0, 0, NULL);
     if (winSta == NULL)
     {
        wprintf(L"CreateWindowStation() failed, error %d!\n", GetLastError());
     }else
        wprintf(L"CreateWindowStation() is OK!\n");
    SetProcessWindowStation(winSta);
    OpenDesktop(L"default", 0, FALSE, READ_CONTROL | WRITE_DAC | DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS | DESKTOP_READOBJECTS);
    wprintf(L"SetProcessWindowStation() after: %x\n", GetProcessWindowStation());
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

and can I make a screenshot of new windows station not is winsta0 and desktop default? please help me :(

---

output

```
SetProcessWindowStation() before: 30
CreateWindowStation() failed, error 5!
SetProcessWindowStation() after: 30
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Is this being run as an administrator? Looking at the docs, only admins are allowed to specify a name. It looks like you can still work around that, though.

Answer (score 6):

Error 5 is `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`

From [CreateWindowStation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682496(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
lpwinsta [in, optional]
```

> The name of the window station to be created. Window station names are
>   case-insensitive and cannot contain backslash characters `\`.
>   Only members of the Administrators group are allowed to specify a name.
>   If `lpwinsta` is `NULL` or an empty string, the system forms a window station
>   name using the logon session identifier for the calling process. To get this name, call the `GetUserObjectInformation` function.

So either start your program as administator or don't specify a name.